# Exponential rule for Whitney-$\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-topology

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M,N,X$ be smooth manifolds. Equip the space of smooth functions between two manifolds with the (strong) Whitney- $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-topology.

The evaluation map $$ev\colon N\times\mathcal{C}^\infty(N,X)\rightarrow X$$ is continuous. (This can e.g. be found in "Margalef-Roig/Dominguez - Differential Topology", Proposition 9.6.7)

Therefore one gets a map of sets $$\mathcal{C}(M,\mathcal{C}^\infty(N,X))\rightarrow \mathcal{C}(M\times N,X).$$

I searched the literature for a reference to the "other direction", but did not find anything. I.e. starting with a smooth map $M\times N\rightarrow X$ I want to know whether the adjoint $M\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty(N,X)$ is continuous or if not, in which cases.

Comment: Ha! My attempt to look this up in an obvious place quickly ran into an obstacle. In Hirsch's _Differential topology_, Exr.2.4.2 (a starred exercise) is essentially identical to your question, without suggesting an answer: "Under what conditions is the natural map $C_S(X,C_S(Y,Z)) \to C_S(X\times Y, Z)$ a homeomorphism?"

Comment: The exercice deals with the continuous case. Hirsch denotes with $C_S$ the topology on the space of all continuous maps coming from considering graphs.

Comment: Time to create an "Ask-Michor-tag". More seriously, Peter Michor, Andreas Kriegl, and collaborators did a lot on such questions for a big variety of function spaces. Look for "convenient calculus".

Comment: @KathrinL. Igor's comment is still relevant. The graph topology on the space of continuous maps *is* the Whitney $C^0$ topology, and Peter Michor's argument works in the continuous case as well.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth or perhaps a "convenient-calculus" tag...

Answer (score 4):

The other direction is not true. The map
$$\mathcal{C}^\infty(M,\mathcal{C}^\infty(N,X))\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty(M\times N,X)$$
is not surjective if $N$ is not compact. The image consists of functions $f$ such that

- for each compact $K\subset M$ there is a compact $L\subset N$ such that $f(x,y)$ is constant in $x\in K$ for each $y\in N\setminus L$.

This is, because smooth (and continuous) curves in $C^\infty (N,X)$ can move only within a compact of $N$ in finite time. See 4.4.4 (page 34) of

- Peter W. Michor: Manifolds of differentiable mappings. Shiva Mathematics Series 3, Shiva Publ., Orpington, (1980), iv+158 pp. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf)

for the very easy proof. There even the continuous case that you ask for is treated.

## Added:

The following might give you feeling for the reason:

Consider $f\in C^\infty(N,\mathbb R)$, equip $C^\infty(N,\mathbb R)$ with the strong Whitney topology. If $t\mapsto t.f$ is continuous $\mathbb R\to C^\infty(N,\mathbb R)$, then $f$ has compact support. Thus $C^\infty_c(N,\mathbb R)$ is the maximal topological vector space in ($C^\infty(N,\mathbb R)$, Whitney topology).

Comment: Motivated by your last paragraph I would like to ask you the following: Is the continuous case true if one restricts to $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(N,\mathbb{R})$? I.e. if I have a smooth map $M\times N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that the adjoint $M\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^\infty(N,\mathbb{R})$ has image in $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(N,\mathbb{R})$, will it be continuous? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the compact-open ($C^\infty$) topology (instead of the Whitney one), then you have continuity/smoothness of the evaluation map and the following exponential laws
$$ C(M \times N, P) = C(M, C(N, P)) $$
$$ C^\infty(M \times N, R) = C^\infty(M, C^\infty(N, R)) $$
if $N$ is a (locally compact) manifold without boundary, $M$ and $P$ are manifolds and $R$ is a vector space (possibly infinite-dimensional).
In particular, for a compact manifold $N$ the above exponential laws also hold for the Whitney topology (which of course coincides with the compact-open topology in this case).

More details can be found for example in some [lecture notes by H. Glöckner](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/Math-Net/Lehrveranstaltungen/Lehrmaterial/SS2005/Liegruppen/skript/ch5vorl.pdf). Also Michor's "Convienient Calculus" book contains a discussion of these matters but there a different topology on the space of smooth maps is used.

Comment: Just to add a citable reference to Tobias comment on the compact-open $C^\infty$ topology: You can find this exponential law as a special version of the general exponential law in https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6510 .